# Exporting test case from selenium IDE 3.1.1.0

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Can't find how to export test case in selenium IDE 3.1.1.0, so I downloaded the 2.9 version and I changed the Firefox browser from version 5.5 to 5.2. After these steps I was able to export the test case but I can't run it in the Firefox because geckodriver needs Firefox 5.5.
The question is can I export somehow the test case from selenium IDE 3.1.1.0?

Answer (score -1):

You may like to use the [katalon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/?src=search) recorder, support selenium and export. After install and try some [selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/?src=search), I found it is the tool record and export code like  python I needed for now.